# Baked Material to Image Texture looks BLURRY

Tags: uv, texture-baking, uv-image-editor

I made this material and when I go to bake the diffuse (or any map) the baked image looks blurry... The image size is set to 4096x4096, and the margins are left at 16... What am I doing wrong?

I understand that a higher resolution will give the baked image better quality, but I'm not really not trying to go higher than 4K.
(Note: I am still a beginner at Texture Baking)

Baked Texture:
[image]

Actual Material being baked:
[image]

Comment: maybe switch the Image Texture from Linear to Closest? Or yes it may be a question of resolution...

Comment: I did try the Closest option when baking AND when previewing the baked result... Nothing.

Comment: maybe share your file?

Comment: I don't believe I can... NDA and all :)